# Turning over a new page

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

[image]

---

#### Transcribed for convenience

```
By ear
Confront aggressively
Flat ground
Going for
Miniature statue
Natural sugar
Rich cakes
Taking without permission
Type of enzyme
Universes

throw
gather
bell sound
bodily fluid
crockery item
law
not poetry
paste
doors
sea parter
```

#### Image attribution

- [Image 1](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ficus_ja01.jpg)
- [Image 2](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tieguanyin2.jpg)
- [Image 3](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gold-flakes.jpg)
- [Image 4](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Romaine.jpg)

Comment: Are we supposed to be able to tell by looking at the images in the middle what they show? It seems reasonably clear what the first and fourth are, but the two middle ones are not so easy to make out...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan If you have the theme you can probably tell what they're meant to represent, but to make things easier I've linked to the original images now.

Comment: I've also just added a visual clue and made two of the clues fairer ("sharp sound" -> "bell sound", "Doing this is a crime" -> "Taking without permission").

Comment: Doesn't change my guess at the latter, does for the former :-).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pictures are

> different types of leaves: fig leaves, tea leaves, gold leaves, and cos (lettuce) leaves.

This leads to the wordplay that

> for each of the words on the top, "FIG", "TEA", "AU" (gold), or "COS" can "leave" the word to become a synonym of one of the words below. In addition, the number of pages behind each picture tells us how many words that picture applies to.

Upon doing that, we get

> By ear = (AU)RALLY -> RALLY = gather
>  Confront aggresively = AC(COS)T -> ACT = law
>  Flat ground = PLATE(AU) -> PLATE = crockery item
>  Going for = (COS)TING -> TING = bell sound
>  Miniature statue = (FIG)URINE -> URINE = bodily fluid
>  Natural sugar = GLU(COS)E -> GLUE = paste
>  Rich cakes = GATE(AU)S -> GATES = doors
>  Taking without permission = S(TEA)LING -> SLING = throw
>  Enzymes = PRO(TEA)SE -> PROSE = not poetry
>  Universes = (COS)MOSES -> MOSES = sea parter

Now, notice that each picture has a number on it. If we

> take them as indicies into the reduced words each picture applies to, and arrange the resulting letters in the order of the grid, we get
>  `LYNNE`
>  `TRUSS`

Now, if we look the name up, we find that

> she is the author of the book, [**Eats, Shoots & Leaves**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eats,_Shoots_%26_Leaves), the final answer, which appropriately includes a similar pun on "leaves" as the one in the puzzle itself (and clued by the title "Turning over a new page", or equivalently turning a *leaf* of a book).

Comment: Right about everything, including the title :)